# Является ли предложение распространённым?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, обращение

Разбираю синтаксически предложение: ***Вставай, страна огромная!***

Обращение второстепенным членом предложения не является.

Значит, нераспространённое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение, состоящее только из главных (главного) членов предложения, называется **нераспространенным**. Если в предложении помимо главных членов есть хотя бы один второстепенный член, то такое предложение называется **распространенным**.

Второстепенные члены — определение, дополнение, обстоятельство.

Обращение грамматически не связано с предложением, **не является членом предложения**, обособляется при помощи запятых, может занимать в предложении любое место.

Источник: http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm.

Интересно, что сами обращения могут также делиться на распространенные и нераспространенные. В приведенном предложении «страна огромная» — обращение, распространенное прилагательным; однако в связи с тем, что само обращение вне зависимости от его (не)распространенности не является членом предложения, на распространенность включающего его предложения оно не влияет.

Осложнение предложения возникает при наличии членов предложения и не являющихся членами предложения единиц с относительной смысловой и интонационной самостоятельностью. Осложнение предложения вызывают:
1) днородные члены,
2) обособленные члены (в том числе уточняющие,   пояснительные, присоединительные, причастный,   деепричастный, сравнительный оборот),
3) вводные слова и предложения, вставные конструкции,
**4) обращения**,
5) прямая речь.

**Таким образом, «Вставай, страна огромная!» — нераспространенное простое предложение, осложненное обращением.**

Answer (score 3):

Предложение **односоставное, нераспространенное, но осложненное обращением.**

ПРОСТОЕ ОСЛОЖНЕННОЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ — простое предложение, в котором присутствуют «осложняющие элементы», выражающие добавочное сообщение. Осложняющие элементы подразделяются на два подтипа. 1- однородные члены предложения и обособленные члены предложения; 2 - слова и словосочетания, не являющиеся членами предложения и не входящие в его структуру: вводные и вставные конструкции, **обращения** и междометия.

https://studopedia.ru/2_117648_otlichie-oslozhnennogo-predlozheniya-ot-neoslozhnennogo-priznaki-oslozhnennogo-predlozheniya.html